Найти вхождение в url по двум ключам, без ошибок в случаи неудачи
document.location.pathname.match(/(news|auto)\-/)[1]

Если url, путь каталогов...
/news-23
/auto-1113

Ок, работает, но в url нет указанных вхождений будет ошибка. При попытке достать значение, которого нет в массиве.
Задача в том, чтобы выполнить определенный код на страницах, в наименовании каталога которого есть указанные вхождения.
Как исправить, выставлять условие, проверять?
Сразу сделать так, чтобы ошибку не выкидывало... Возможно?
Не спец в регулярках, если возможно выполнить все тоже самое, только уже на
document.URL

Будет круто, после домена, после первого слеша должно быть вхождение либо news либо auto.
True - выполняем следующий код
False - лишь бы ошибку js не выкидывал. Иначе скрипт не работает...

Я думаю вам подойдёт оператор опциональной последовательности — ?.
document.location.pathname.match(/(news|auto)\-/)?.[1]

или
document.URL.match(/(news|auto)\-/)?.[1]

Как вам удобнее, который вернёт либо значение, либо undefined без каких-либо ошибок.


[ '/news-23',
  '/auto-1113',
  '/',
  '/foo',
  'https://my.site/news-23',
  'https://my.site/auto-1113',
  'https://my.site/',
  'https://my.site',
  'https://my.site/foo',
].forEach((dlp) => {
  console.log( dlp.match(/(news|auto)\-/)?.[1] )
})



А уж как воспользоваться этим... вам виднее, поскольку у нас нет перед глазами кода вашей обработки.
